# how to setup perfino agent in tomcat 9 server on windows OS?

Tags: java, jprofiler, javaagents, catalina, perfino

I´m trying to install perfino jar on production that can monitor Java Spring MVC web transactions and I need to put a javaagent into my Tomcat 9 server on windows somehow but am not clear on exactly how to do this, I am using Windows server and have been instructed by the software company that makes this product to do something like below:

```
-javaagent:C:\Program Files\perfino\agent\perfino.jar
```

Do i need to insert the above line into startup.bat or catlina.bat and any format i need to follow?

```
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Start script for the CATALINA Server
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

setlocal
rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
:gotHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
echo The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end
```

Kindly advise me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-javagent` is a VM parameter, it has to be inserted in the command line after the java executable and before the main class name.

The start scripts for Tomcat support an environment variable `CATALINA_OPTS`. In startup.bat, you can insert the line

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-javaagent:C:\Program Files\perfino\agent\perfino.jar" %CATALINA_OPTS%
```

before the call to

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" run %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

Comment: I have added like below and startup.bat immediately close after i click it.tomcat is not starting. I have updated my question with the startup.bat file.


:okHome
set CATALINA_OPTS=-javaagent:C:\Program Files\perfino\agent\perfino.jar %CATALINA_OPTS%
set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat"

Comment: How to do setup for linux?

Comment: what is the difference between perfino and jprofiler. You have given option to attach a jvm from jprofiler itself and so why i need to use perfino? kindly advise.

Comment: For Linux it's the same, just replace set with "export". perfino is a low overhead monitoring tool and JProfiler is a development profiler.

Answer (score 0):

After i have added " " to the above answer,it started working.

set CATALINA_OPTS=-javaagent:"C:\Program Files\perfino\agent\perfino.jar" %CATALINA_OPTS%